# ActionScript3: regex expression for password that checks number of characters

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I'm trying to use a regex expression in AS3/Flex4.6 to check for passwords meeting the following criteria:

1. Between 6 and 15 characters
2. Must contain at least one lower case letter
3. Must contain at least one upper case letter
4. Must contain at least one number (e.g 0-9)

So far, here is what I'm using:

```
<mx:RegExpValidator source="{loginPwd}" property="text" 
     expression="^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[A-Z])\w*$"  
     valid="rh(event);" invalid="rh(event);"/>
```

It does everything except catch password length of 6 to 15 characters. I could use a `StringValidator` to do this, but I'd rather have the `RegExpValidator` do both (so that I don't have the situation where multiple error messages are displayed for one TextInput field, e.g. one for each validator).

I've tried the following regex expressions, but while they compile, they do not work (for example, `aaAA33` doesn't pass).

```
expression="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,15})"
expression="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,15}"
expression="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,15}^$"
expression="^.*(?=.{6,15})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$"
```

Comment: Have you tried your initial regex with anchor `^ $` characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your expression with my Regex testtool on the mac

```
 "((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,15})" - works
 "^.*(?=.{6,15})(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$" - works
```

works like intended.
Did you try to match the string with a normal actionscript regex pattern? I did.

```
public function runTest():void
{
    var testArray:Array = ["aaBB99","aaaaa99","AAAAAAA","A3b","A3bdsdsdsd"];
    var reg:RegExp = new RegExp("^.*(?=.{6,15})(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$");

    for each ( var value:String in testArray )
    {
        trace(value.match(reg));
    }
}
```

the output was:

```
[trace] aaBB99
[trace] null
[trace] null
[trace] null
[trace] A3bdsdsdsd
```

See no problem here

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "normal actionscript regex pattern", but everything I tested was using input from a TextInput box along with RegExpValidator.

Comment: I mean what I did in my example. Just to check if it is a problem in the validator or your pattern

Comment: Some related links showing the RegExpValidator works differently than using the test method of the regular expression object.  http://forums.adobe.com/thread/833597  and  http://www.opencoder.co.uk/2010/03/regexpvalidator-issues/  I think it's just a matter of figuring out which characters need to be escaped, but I can't find any documentation for that regarding RexExpValidator.

Comment: Then write your own. Your could provide it with a static regex. No need to escape string values etc. You know what you need.

Comment: Yes, I could do that but in the beginning I thought "why reinvent the wheel" so to speak. I didn't expect to find any problems. Well, turns out all I need (for my expression above at least) is to escape the curly brackets. Now, this expression works `expression="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).\{6,15\})"`

Comment: Thanks so much Larusso, really appreciated your answer here.

Comment: Cool that you found your solution.